# Check if user scrolled to the TOP of window - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, vertical-scrolling

With respect to below code, I'm notified if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page leaving 50px from the vertical end.

```
(document.body.clientHeight + window.pageYOffset + 50) >= document.body.scrollHeight
```

Similarly, I want to know if the user has scrolled to the top of the page leaving 50px from the vertical start.

I tried something like this:

```
window.pageYOffset < document.body.clientHeight
```

This is not working as I only need to execute this code if the user scrolls top but the above line also gets valid if user scrolls down in the top area.

I'm not using a (scroll) event but a HostListener, like this:

```
@HostListener('window:Scroll',['$event'])
onWindowsScroll(){
    //Logic Here
}
```

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

If the user has scrolled to the top of the page leaving 50px from the vertical start, you can modify your logic inside the onWindowsScroll() function

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onWindowsScroll(event: Event) {
  const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop <= 50) {
    // Execute your code here
  }
}
```

event listener is bound to 'window:scroll', which will trigger the function whenever the user scrolls the page. Inside the function, the scrollTop value is calculated using window.pageYOffset, which is supported in most modern browsers, as well as fallbacks for older browsers (document.documentElement.scrollTop and document.body.scrollTop).

hope it's helps